# How to debug an empty response after a POST request

Tags: android, post, httpurlconnection

I seldom get an empty response after a POST request in Android. The response headers and error stream are also empty.

Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

Is there something else I can do to debug this on the client side? I suspect it's some kind of bug of the `HttpURLConnection`, but I don't know how to get more info from it.

```
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setDoInput(true);
con.setDoOutput(true);
ostream = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
// Write POST params to ostream
ostream.flush();
return (InputStream) con.getContent(); // This sometimes returns an empty stream
```

Comment: Did you solve that issue? I'm facing the same, but not always, reraly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maybe try running WireShark or some other packet analyzer and see exactly what you are sending and what you are getting back.